# How can I group boolean fields in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Here's a very simple data example.

```json
[
  {
    "aaa": true,
    "bbb": 111,
    
  },
  {
    "aaa": false,
    "bbb": 111,
    
  }
]
```

Then, what query should be executed so that I can get the result like this?

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "0",
    "bbb_sum": 222,
    "aaa_and": false,
    "aaa_or": true
  }
]
```

Actually, I've tried with a query like this

```py
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "0",
      "bbb_sum": {
        "$sum": "$bbb"
      },
      "aaa_and": {
        "$and": ["$aaa", true]
      },
      "aaa_or": {
        "$or": ["$aaa", false]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

But the Mongo Playground complains `query failed: (Location40237) The $and accumulator is a unary operator`, that's quite confusing.

You can also find this simple test case here https://mongoplayground.net/p/8dqtXJ93vIx

Also, I've searched for similar questions on both Google and Stackoverflow, but I can't find one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not like "$sum","$and" and "$or" are not aggregation operators that can be used in "$group". You can temporary save all the "aaa" field into an array and then use "$project" operator to process the data.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "0",
      "sum": {
        "$sum": "$bbb"
      },
      "aaa_all": {
        "$push": "$aaa"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "sum": 1,
      "aaa_and": {
        "$allElementsTrue": "$aaa_all"
      },
      "aaa_or": {
        "$anyElementTrue": "$aaa_all"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the case: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y-Fs_Ch9lwk

Comment: Very concise and easy-understanding solution! Thank you. Just one quick question, what does the `"sum": 1` mean in the `$project` part? 
I found I can either use 1, 2, or something else, both are working.

Comment: allElementsTrue ll return true for empty arrays. Keep this is also in mind. It's a nice approach. +1

Comment: @kaixinliu You can use any positive number.

Comment: @Gibbs, yes you are correct, we'll need to pay attention to the "empty array issue". Thanks.

Comment: @kaixinliu "sum": 1 means to project the "sum" field directly. As Gibbs mentioned, any positive number is ok.

Comment: Or use `$min` and `$max` respectively as `$and` and `$or` operators directly in the `$group` stage. See detailed answer below : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69438862/4399725

Answer (score 3):

`$min` and `$max` operators actually work with booleans too, `false` being considered smaller than `true`

thinking of them as 0 and 1 might be easier to understand :

- `$min: [a,…,n]` will return 1/true only if all elements are 1/true => this is a AND
- `$max: [a,…,n]` will return 0/false only if all elements are 0/false => this is a OR

(the operators will return booleans if input booleans, the analogy with numbers is only for the sake of comprehension)

So your request can simply become :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "0",
      "bbb_sum": {
        "$sum": "$bbb"
      },
      "aaa_and": {
        "$min": "$aaa"
      },
      "aaa_or": {
        "$max": "$aaa"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do some logics as below

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {//Group by desired id
      "_id": null,
      "sum": {//Sum the value
        "$sum": "$bbb"
      },
      "aaa_and": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$aaa",
                true
              ]
            },
            "then": 1, //If true returns 1
            "else": 0 // else 0
          }
        }
      },
      "total": { //helper to do the logic
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      aaa_and: {
        "$eq": [//If total matches with number of true, all are true
          "$total",
          "$aaa_and"
        ]
      },
      aaa_or: {
        "$ne": [//if value greater than 0, then there is at least one true
          "$aaa_and",
          "0"
        ]
      },
      sum: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mflksctsIk5)

Comment: Very nice solution! Thank you!